# Google Maps Textured Roads

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to find a Google Maps API v3 friendly way to add textures (my own images) to elements such as roads, grass, and water.  I know you can change the colors of various elements, but I want to do more.

I'm curious if anyone knows if this can be done at a large scale (not just a single area but the whole world).

I have some ideas beyond the API but I would like to see if this could work first.

Thanks.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you might have a small GIF or PNG--just a few pixels wide and high--that you would like to be laid over roads sort of like a background image or wallpaper for the road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I do not believe that there is currently a way to do that easily and reliably using Google Maps API v3.

If I wanted to have such a feature, I'd look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) and [Google Earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/).  I have no idea if either support such a feature, but that's where I'd look first.

You may be able to do something fairly involved to achieve this affect with Google Maps API v3, but it might be a lot of work and could be very difficult to do reliably.

Comment: Thanks Trott.  There are definitely some ways I've found to avoid it, but they are hacks and I would prefer to play nice with the API if possible.  I will look into OpenLayers. OpenStreetMap is another alternative.